# Firestore merge two collections into one

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project where we have an iOS and an Android app and we are using Firestore as the backend. Now I have discovered that we write the same data in two separate collections.

For example, we have the class user, with id name, etc.
Android writes it in the user collection and ios in the basicUser collection.

Is there a way to merge these two tables into one in Firestore?

Merge two Firestore tables into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no tool that can help you merge the documents of two collections into a single one. What you have to do, is to copy the documents in one collection to the other collection. Besides that, to avoid future issues, keep the same name in both iOS and Android applications. For example, if you consider using the name of the collection `user` instead of `basicUser`, then make sure both applications use the exact same `user` name in the code.

IMH, the best option that you have to solve this issue, is to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

P.S. After you copy all documents from one collection to the other one, make also sure to delete the documents from the older collection.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to create path by using id.

```
//refrences
const studentsCollectionRef = collection(db, "students")
const oldStdRef = collection(db, "stdPrevData")


const getStudents = async () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    try {
      const getStudents = query(studentsCollectionRef);
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(getStudents);
      const student = []
      await Promise.all(
        querySnapshot?.docs.map(async (docs) => {
          if (docs?.data()?.studentOldRecord) {
            const docRef = doc(oldStdRef, docs?.data()?.studentOldRecord);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
            student.push({ ...docs.data(), id: docs?.id, ...docSnap?.data() })
          } else {
            student.push({ ...docs.data(), id: docs?.id })
          }

        })
      )
      resolve(student)

    } catch (error) {
      reject("reject")

      console.log(error)
      console.log(error, "faild to get student")
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**